# Does calling ActiveMQConnection cleanup and changeuserinfo impact DefaultMessageListenerContainer with CACHE_CONSUMER

Tags: oauth, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Here's some context: I've set up an ActiveMQBroker (version 5.13.1) with a BrokerPlugin that takes a requestId (just a UUID for tracking requests across different servers) and OAuth token (more about the OAuth token below) in the 'username' and 'password' fields, respectively, of the org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo ... it's based on [this great post](http://mariuszprzydatek.com/2014/01/04/token-based-authentication-plugin-for-activemq/). On the client/consumer side, I'm wrapping the ActiveMQConnection inside of a Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer (version 4.2.4-RELEASE) with cacheLeve=CACHE_CONSUMER (so it also caches the Session and Consumer along with the Connection).

The snag is that the client's OAuth token expires every 20 minutes, so I've set up a ScheduledExecutorService on the client side to refresh the OAuth token every 18 minutes.

My question is that if my scheduled task on the client side calls ActiveMQConnection#cleanup() followed by ActiveMQConnection#changeUserInfo(newRequestId, newAuthToken) ... will that negatively impact spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer that is holding onto that same ActiveMQConnection? Or another way to ask, is there a "right" way for my client code to set the new "username" and "password" fields in the ActiveMQConnection without messing anything up in the DefaultMessageListenerContainer? I'm especially concerned with any multi-threading issues since the DefaultMessageListenerContainer has several consumer threads ... and my ScheduledExecutorService is, of course, running it's own thread to update the OAuth token into the ActiveMQConnection.

Would it be enough to extend DefaultMessageListenerContainer and wrap my update of the OAuth token inside a synchronized block of the 'sharedConnectionMonitor', e.g. would something the following be necessary and/or sufficient:

```
public class OAuthMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {
    public void updateOAuthToken(String requestId, String authToken) throws JMSException {
        synchronized(sharedConnectionMonitor) {
            ActiveMQConnection amqConn = (ActiveMQConnection)getSharedConnection();
            amqConn.doCleanup(true);
            amqConn.changeUserInfo(requestId, authToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW here's how I solved the issue:

1) I first had to upgrade ActiveMQ from 5.13.0 to 5.13.3 because 5.13.0 had a thread deadlock issue with the FailoverTransport when trying to reconnect to the broker after the transport was interrupted, e.g. network glitch, server restart, zookeeper electing a new "master" broker (we're using replicated leveldb on the server with 3 brokers)

2) After working past the thread deadlock in ActiveMQ I realized that changing the username and password on the ActiveMQConnection basically resets the whole connection anyway ... which means the DMLC is reset ... so I made a subclass of DMLC that I could reset from a TransportListener on the connection when the transport is interrupted ... but then ran into another thread deadlock in the DMLC ... and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911642/6035631) that helped me past that.

The subclass of DMLC just needs this method:

```
public void restart() {
    try {
        shutdown();
        initialize();
        start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Could not restart DMLC", e);
    }
}
```

and the transport listener needs to do this:

```
@Override
public void transportInterrupted() {
    dmlc.restart();
}
```